# Open multiple websites one after another in one firefox window only

Tags: shell-script, firefox

`/root/file` has

```
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackexchange.com
https://reddit.com
```

I need to open all these websites one after another in one `firefox` window only. Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do 
    if pgrep firefox; 
    then 
        firefox --new-tab "$line" ; 
    else 
        firefox "$line" ;
    fi 
done < /root/file
```

I tried `nohup` also but it didn't work.

The problem is that if I use `;` it would bind to shell process and won't run the next command until I exit out of `firefox` and if I use `nohup` or `&` , it would be separated from the shell and will open the new window of `firefox` instead of new tab. In both cases, every website opens in new window.

---

## Partially Solved

`xdg-open` opens websites in one window when commands are manually typed on the shell like

```
$ xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com
$ xdg-open https://stackexchange.com
$ xdg-open https://reddit.com
```

but it doesn't work in script. I have the following script with `xdg-open`

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do 
    xdg-open "$line"
done < /root/file
```

but it again opens websites in different windows instead single window.

Comment: Can you change the lines to start with `http://` or `https://`?  Then, instead of calling `firefox` you could just `open` it which will navigate to it with your default browser.  I recently discovered (with chrome anyway) if you `open site1; open site2; open site3` they will all open in separate tabs in the same window but if you break it into different lines each will open in a new window.

Comment: @Jesse_b I did `open https://stackexchange.com`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jesse_b `xdg-open` works though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that it takes some time for Firefox to start. If you run it in the background, next time you do `firefox --new-tab`, your first instance has not quite started and is not ready to open another tab. You must wait some time after starting the first Firefox instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    if pgrep -u $USER firefox > /dev/null
    then
        firefox --new-tab "$line" &
    else
        firefox "$line" &
        sleep 3                 # You may want to tune this value
    fi < /dev/null
done < /root/file
```

Beware that with this kind of construct any program in your loop may eat what comes from `stdin` and this will end your loop prematurely. That's why I have preventively added `< /dev/null` to the `if` part.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to:

`firefox https://stackoverflow.com https://stackexchange.com https://reddit.com`

According to mozilla's [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

> -url URL
>
> Open URL in a new tab or window, depend on the browser option. -url can be omitted. You may list multiple URLs, separated by spaces. Firefox and SeaMonkey only.

So you can write your script as

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox $(cat /root/file | tr '\n' ' ') &
```